# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, разделёнными придаточным

Tags: пунктуация

> Площадь Республики, через которую вы только что прошли, – так же, как
>   и здание, часть терм Диоклетиана.

Запятая после "прошли" - моя, остальное авторское; стало быть, хочет тире, -

где ему место?

Можно без разговоров выбросить (или перенести?), но тогда заблудишься в запятых...

*Площадь Республики, через которую вы только что прошли, так же, как и здание, часть терм Диоклетиана.*

Так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тире возможно, хотя и не обязательно (тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным именительным падежом сущ., но между ними есть ещё конструкции).

Где бы мы поставили "это", там и тире, а значит, перед "часть терм":

Площадь Республики, через которую вы только что прошли, так же как и здание, - часть терм Диоклетиана.

И союз "так же как и" здесь не расчленяется запятой.